# Condition in the foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do something simple - compare a value with an item in an array and then run a condition based on the comparison.

Here's my array:

```
$states = ['AL','AR','CT','DE','FL','GA','IL','IN','IA','KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','NE','NH','NJ','NY','NC','ND','OH','OK','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','VT','VA','WV','WI'];
```

Here's the rest of my code with my foreach function:

```
$region = '';
$array_length = count($states);
foreach($states as $state_item){
    if($state_item == $state) {
         $region = 'E';
    } else {
         $region = 'W';
    }
}

echo $region;
```

So far my code only successfully gets to the ELSE part of my condition and prints out the W. So it basically doesn't even compute the IF part. It's been a long time since I've done PHP. Please remind me/correct me if there's a better way of accomplishing this.

`$state` is being pulled in from a DB by a query and is working properly.

ENDED UP USING A FOREACH LOOP with an array declared as `$states = array(...)` for it to not throw a server error (500) at me.

Comment: use  if(strcmp($state_item,$state)==0);   or   $state_item===$state;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that after `$state_item == $state` is `true` and `$region` is `E`, the foreach loop keeps running. With the next iteration `$state_item == $state` is `false`, and `$region` is overwritten as `W`.

To fix it, with your code:

```
$region = 'W';
foreach($states as $state_item){
    if($state_item == $state) {
         $region = 'E';
         break; // stop here
    }
}
```

A better way to do so:

```
if (in_array($state, $states)) {
    $region = 'E'; 
} else {
    $region = 'W';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped and makes perfect sense! Your second solution I've tried before I started using the foreach loop. in_array works perfectly on my localhost but the server currently runs php version 5.3.3 and it does not support in_array (gives a 500 error too when trying to use it). That being not my personal server and it having multiple websites on it, it would be complicated to update the php version. Thus the loop.

Comment: `in_array` exists from php4: are you sure that that 500 error is not something else? Check your logs. If that works for you, then considers of accept one of this answers.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer ternary operator for simple cases like this one:

```
$region = in_array($state, $states) ? 'E' : 'W';
```

Comment: in_array would be beautiful and works perfectly on my localhost but the server currently runs php version 5.3.3 and it does not support in_array (gives a 500 error too when trying to use it). Thus the loop.

Comment: [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) was introduced in php 4. Your 500 error has another reason. You can place the following code at the end of your script and see the actual error: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score -1):

instead of loop you can directly use ternary operator:

```
$region = in_array($state, $states) ? 'E' : 'W';
```

Comment: in_array would be beautiful and works perfectly on my localhost but the server currently runs php version 5.3.3 and it does not support in_array (gives a 500 error too when trying to use it). Thus the loop.